# How to apply softmax to CNN-LSTM time series

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, softmax

I've build the following model:

```
steps=52
fips=1263
features=92
classes=6 

modelo = Sequential()
#CNN
modelo.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(16,(3),activation='relu',padding='same'),
                                  input_shape=(steps,fips,features)))
modelo.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=(2))))
modelo.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(32,(3),activation='relu',padding='same'),
                                  input_shape=(steps,fips,features)))
modelo.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=(2))))
modelo.add(Dropout(0.2))

modelo.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
#LSTM
modelo.add(LSTM(units=100, return_sequences=False))

modelo.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
modelo.add(Dense(classes, activation='softmax'))

modelo.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

modelo.fit(data_tensor,out_tensor,epochs=10)
```

The shape of the data_tensor is (52,1263,92) and from the out_tensor (52,1263,6).

I get the following error when training:

```
 ValueError: Shapes (None, 52, 1263, 6) and (None, 6) are incompatible
```

The Dense layer with softmax function doesn't accept that are passes a shape, it only accepts int values. So I think I have to use a different layer to apply softmax and get my classes probabilities. Which on do I use, or is there something different I can try?

I've tried:

- Changing LSTM return_sequences = True, but I get a very similar error message, but (None,52,6) instead of (None,6)
- I've also tried to change the shape of the out_tensor to a more flattened shape (65676, 6) and I get a different version of a value error:

  ```
  ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
        x sizes: 1
        y sizes: 65676
        Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the summary of the model, this may help :

```
Model: "sequential_2"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 time_distributed_9 (TimeDis  (None, 52, 1263, 16)     4432      
 tributed)                                                       
                                                                 
 time_distributed_10 (TimeDi  (None, 52, 631, 16)      0         
 stributed)                                                      
                                                                 
 time_distributed_11 (TimeDi  (None, 52, 631, 32)      1568      
 stributed)                                                      
                                                                 
 time_distributed_12 (TimeDi  (None, 52, 315, 32)      0         
 stributed)                                                      
                                                                 
 dropout_1 (Dropout)         (None, 52, 315, 32)       0         
                                                                 
 time_distributed_13 (TimeDi  (None, 52, 10080)        0         
 stributed)                                                      
                                                                 
 lstm_1 (LSTM)               (None, 100)               4072400   
                                                                 
 dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 100)               10100     
                                                                 
 dense_3 (Dense)             (None, 6)                 606       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 4,089,106
Trainable params: 4,089,106
Non-trainable params: 0
```